# d3.js time parsing with milliseconds not working?

Tags: javascript, datetime, d3.js

Is there a workaround to get D3.js to parse datetimes that have milliseconds included? I can't get this to work:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").parse
parseDate("2011-01-01T12:14:35")
//that works

parseDate("2011-01-01T12:14:35.3456")
//returns null
```

Answer (score 5):

If your dateTime strings are already in that format, you don't need d3 to parse it into an actual date object.

For example:

```
new Date("2011-01-01T12:14:35")
# Sat Jan 01 2011 04:14:35 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

results in a correct date object.

Answer (score 5):

Include format to parse the miliseconds which uses %L [source](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting).

For your case:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S").parse
parseDate("2011-01-01T12:14:35")    //that works

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L").parse
parseDate("2011-01-01T12:14:35.345")    // works
```

Note that you provided 4 digits as milliseconds, which I think is not true if you are dealing with milliseconds. If you really have 4 digits or 6 digits (microseconds) and you are only interested in milliseconds, you can filter off the last few digits. For example:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L000").parse
parseDate("2011-01-01T12:14:35.345000")    //that works
```

Answer (score 3):

Try looking at the `d3.time.format.iso` formatting function, shown on the wiki page: [d3.time.format.iso](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-format_iso).

Comment: I think I tried that, and that the decimals threw it off. Will look into it again.

Comment: how to parse "2013-07-26T17:07:17.554Z" to get hours minutes and date?var format = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S"); is not working. it is returning null